# Swift Range Type endIndex

Tags: swift, range

If you create a var Range = 0...0, I would expect the endIndex to be zero. But in reality is 1.

```
var myRange: Range<Int> = 0...0
print("start Index \(myRange.startIndex) End Index \(myRange.endIndex)")
```

> output: "start Index 0 End Index 1"

How can I question a Range instance if an Index of type Int is contained ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `endIndex` is not actually included in the `Range`.  The `Range` is `startIndex ..< endIndex`.  So, for your example, `0...0` is stored as `0..<1` which means the same thing.

For **Swift 1.2** you can use the global function `contains` to check if an `Int` is contained by a `Range`:

```
var myRange: Range<Int> = 0...0
let i: Int = 1

if contains(myRange, i) {
    println("yes")
} else {
    println("no")    // prints "no"
}
```

For **Swift 2.0**:

```
var myRange: Range<Int> = 0...0
let i: Int = 1

if myRange.contains(i) {
    print("yes")
} else {
    print("no")    // prints "no"
}
```

Comment: Yes. When I type `var myRange: Range<Int> = 0...0` in playground ,the output is `"0..<1"`.

Comment: Indeed.  The Swift designers apparently chose to standardize on the half-open range version.

Comment: Thanks. And when I tried to do the experiment like `var myRange: Range<Int> = 1..<0`, there is no output. Is that an undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could refer to [Half-Open Range Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

```
 var myRange: Range<Int> = 0..<0
```

> outputs:"start Index 0 End Index 0"

The half-open range operator `(a..<b)` defines a range that runs from a to b, but does not include b.  And the closed range operator `(a...b)` will finally turn to `(a..<b+1)`

Answer (score 0):

Because `Range` is also a collection, you can use its `minElement()` and `maxElement()` methods, which will return the correct index, respecting the range being closed (`...`) or half-open (`..<`).

So the below code will output zeros as expected:

```
let range: Range<Int> = 0...0
let min = range.minElement()!
let max = range.maxElement()!
print("min=\(min), max=\(max)")
// Output: "min=0, max=0"
```

*Note:* both methods have `O(elements.count)` complexity which might not be suitable for some cases.